# How was こき使う formed?

Tags: meaning, translation, words, etymology

I was reading a manga called *Rengoku ni Warau* and Kaishin said:

- ったく、人をこき使いやがって

  あのジジィほっつき歩いてやがる

Jisho says that こき使い means pushing someone around or to work someone hard but it doesn't seem to fit with the context. Kaishin said that to Goemon, a fellow ninja that was trying to convince him to desert the battlefield and who has been by Tanba's (ジジィ's) side for many years, so I don't think "pushing someone around" would be a good translation.

Moreover, I would like to know the origin of こき使い's こき.

Comment: By any chance, isn't どこ(を) missing before ほっつき歩いて?

Comment: Just a note that the entry on Jisho does show what こき comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こき使う is a compound verb made of [扱く](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%89%B1%E3%81%8F) and 使う. 扱く can be read both as こく and しごく (こく is less common), but they originally mean roughly the same thing, "to rub/scrub", and by extension, "to work someone hard". From [Compound Verb Lexicon](https://db4.ninjal.ac.jp/vvlexicon/db/):

[image: screenshot]

I don't know the story, but こき使う only means "to work someone hard". Do you understand 人 in this context probably refers to "me", the speaker? 人をこき使いやがって means "[Someone] is driving me like a horse".

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I initially thought he was referring to Goemon. Thanks!